# Integrating informatica with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, informatica

I am planning to use Kafka Data Objects in Informatica BDM.
I want to read the data from Kafka every 5 minutes through Informatica BDM. I have few queries how Kafka recognizes the current offset from which it has to load.
Can we set the offset of a topic from which Informatica need to load the incremental or changed data in the Kafka Data Object ???
I found the below answers, could you please correct me the exact process it follows:
1) Does the Zookeeper store the current offset till where data has been loaded.
2) To read the messages after last committed offset, we need to set the auto.offset.reset parameter in the Consumer configuration file as largest.

Please suggest me an approach how to fetch the data from Kafka.

Regards,

Srinath

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions,

1. The old consumer API stores the offsets in ZooKeeper. The new consumer API, however, stores the offsets in an internal topic in Kafka.
2. Within a consumer group, A Kafka Consumer, by default, starts consuming messages from the last committed offset. The config `auto.offset.reset` comes into play when no committed offset exists for the consumer group. For example, when a consumer starts consuming as part of a new consumer group this config determines where in the log (start of the log or end of the log) it should start from.

Comment: Thanks Vahid for the solutions. Can u suggest me approach on how to read Kafka data from Informatica (BDM or Power Center).

Comment: I'd love to help, but I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Informatica. Perhaps someone who knows the product can comment and provide additional help.